# NVARCHAR(MAX) Always Encrypted and EF6 throwing error on update

Tags: entity-framework, always-encrypted

The 'clash' exception is happening updating NVARCHAR(MAX) using EF6 on an always encrypted field. Is this avoidable?

Tried changing the data type via latest SSMS and also getting 'clash' errors. Seems that now I have encrypted the columns I cannot alter the table at all either.

Comment: [This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlsecurity/2015/08/27/using-always-encrypted-with-entity-framework-6/) may shed some light.

Comment: Unfortunately not

Comment: Could you please provide the complete error message that you are getting?

Comment: I don't have it handy - basically if the field is nvarchar(max) and encrypted, you cannot save an update to it. Try to repro - I don't think I was doing anything special. It's the typical 'blah blah cannot save clash because of nvarchar not nvarchar(max) or something' error that always seems to happen with this always encrypted stuff